# Advanced wind electricity generation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, solid-mechanics, technology, econo-physics

Well, when it comes to electricity generation it is important to design units to be scalable enough.
With wind turbines becoming popular nowadays it is very important.
As you know, currently wind turbines are placed on surface, mostly at hills and small mountains.
But why placing it on surface, where the wind speed is very limited ?
Why not placing it in some cloudy heights, where the wind constantly flows at really large speeds 24 hours a day ?

One can argue that it is technically difficult to get heavy turbines at heights and costly transport energy to the land via cables.
But what about using wind kite farm cell structs ?
These kind of units can be easily scaled via structs attachments and are capable of carrying huge amounts of generating fans.

Moreover, in this case there is no need of placing heavy generators in kites and send them to air.
You can easily transfer the torque moment from fans in the air to the generators on land using the cords, connecting the kite to the land.
That means it is easy to create really large generating volumes in the air and transfer huge amounts of useful work to the land.

Also kites and fans are very cheap in mass production and can be easily installed almost anywhere.
If you think that wind power is just not enough – think about heavy hurricanes and typhoons that deal really a lot of damage to civilians all around the world.
This scalable devices can easily dissipate all that energy and convert it to useful electricity.
I guess an array of 10-50 small cheap generating cubes like 100-400 meters in length can easily handle small hurricanes.

So why are we still using ineffective heavy structures with generators instead of this kind of structs ?

Comment: how close can they be placed without worrying about getting them entangled?

Comment: Well, you could use a kind of cubes with spherical balanced fans with 2 degrees of freedom to catch the correct wind direction. That will ensure maximum effectiveness in terms of flow surface with no entanglement at all.

Comment: This makes these structs easy and scalable just like Lego constructors with no limits on structure size

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand the structure you intend to fly, what sort of size are we talking about?  Modern wind turbines are very large.  Is this a kite hte size of a 737?

Comment: Thats the point - we are not limited to any fan size, since the generators are placed on land. The generating cube structures could be of any size and are really light. They consist of small cells and can be combined to any size in large clusters.